# Обрезать строку между определенными символами

Tags: javascript, jquery

Помогите решить на JS, нужно из строки (в нее помещен текущий урл) вырезать все дополнительные Get параметры, оставить только последний параметр.
Пример строки:

> /poslednie-tovary/?sort=p.sort_order&order=ASC&category=20

Нужно оставить только:

> /poslednie-tovary/?category=20

Прошу подсказать, по сути нужно вырезать все от знака вопроса до последнего "&", параметров до последнего может быть несколько

Comment: Уточните, вам нужно оставить именно последний параметр или именно параметр category? Что делать, если последним будет не category?

Comment: Уточните, вам нужно оставить именно последний параметр или именно параметр category? Что делать, если последним будет не category?

Comment: Нужно оставить именно последний get - category=20? он всегда будет последним, его формирует php, там все настроено. То есть нужно вырезать между знаком вопроса и последним & включительно

Comment: Дак добавьте вы в ссылку, а у ссылки есть параметр `search`. А дальше уже отсеить не нужные и склеить.

Comment: Он не всегда будет последним. Что если пользователь руками отредактирует ссылку и сделает category первым? Что если вы сами поменяете порядок параметров через полгода и забудете учесть, что привязались к последнему параметру? Не подставляйте грабли ни себе, ни пользователям, если вам нужно оставить только category - так и скажите, без всяких "последних"

Comment: Это не критично, так как с помощью этого просто разворачиваю меню-гармошку, максимум что будет, меню не раскроется, я готов этим пожертвовать

Comment: [нытьё] Вот стараешься учить людей делать хорошо, а они сопротивляются и продолжают делать плохо, эх [/нытьё]

Comment: Ну согласен с вами) Но к такому урл дойдет процентов 10 посетителей, я не думаю что даже 50 % от тех что дошли захотят поменять урл..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если необходимо оставлять именно последний GET-параметр, то первые два варианта:

```js
init();
let url = '/poslednie-tovary/?sort=p.sort_order&order=ASC&category=20', 
    newUrl; 

// 1. split ➝ конкатенация 
newUrl = url.split(/[?&]/); 
newUrl = `${newUrl[0]}?${newUrl[newUrl.length - 1]}`; 
writeToBody('1. ' + newUrl); 

// 2. split ➝ splice ➝ join 
newUrl = url.split(/[?&]/); 
newUrl.splice(1, newUrl.length - 2); 
newUrl = newUrl.join('?'); 
writeToBody('2. ' + newUrl); 

// 3. регулярное выражение (в отличие от предыдущих вариантов, оставляет именно параметр "category")
newUrl = url.replace(/\?(.*)(category=[^&]+)/, '?$2'); 
writeToBody('3. ' + newUrl); 


// тут ничего интересного, пара функций для вывода в бади
function init() { document.body.style.cssText = 'font: 18px monospace; white-space: pre-line;'; document.body.textContent = ''; }
function writeToBody(str) { document.body.textContent += str + '\n'; }
```

[Тест всех трех способов на jsPerf](https://jsperf.com/so-814898/1).

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно

Comment: @BogdanNovik, пожалуйста :) В ответ добавлены еще два способа и тест - возможно, Вам будет интересно.